# wcf passing list as method parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, list, generics

I have a wcf service which has a method as follow:

```
 public void SyncClient(List<Client> client)
        {
         }
```

then i call this in a lib solution which has reference to this service as follow:

```
WCF.SyncClient wcfSer = new WCF.SyncClient();
 List<Client> clientModified = secondservice.Get_Clients(ModifiedDate, modifiedUnt).ToList();
wcfSer.SyncClient(clientModified);
```

but I keep on getting the following error :

```
The best overloaded method match for 'SyncClient(SyncLib.ClientWCF.Client[])' has some invalid arguments    
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SyncLib.Client>' to 'SyncLib.WCF.Client[]'
```

The only thing I am doing is getting the list populated with another web service.

what is the problem here as the argument that I am passing is list and the method accepts list, can some one please point me to right direction.

Comment: Did you generate the proxy by adding a service reference in VS?  There is a setting in there to serialize collections as... (Array, List, Dictionary, etc) under the advance options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to how you added the service reference.

You can either amend your code to send client[]

```
WCF.SyncClient wcfSer = new WCF.SyncClient();
 var clientModified = secondservice.Get_Clients(ModifiedDate,
    modifiedUnt).ToArray();
wcfSer.SyncClient(clientModified);
```

or re-add the reference and select the option to use System.Collection.Generic.List as below;

```
Select Add Reference
Select URL
Select Advanced when you have found the service.
In Datatype, you will see these options.
```

Select Collection Type as `System.Collection.Generic.List`

Comment: I followed your steps as in delete the service and re add with option changed, but sill getting same error

Comment: @Sam1  which option did you try?

Comment: am getting this error now cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SyncLib.TaskEngine.Client>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SyncLib.ClientWCF.Client>'

Comment: but both services use same dto

Comment: And the error is the same? What does method signature look like now in the proxy class?

Comment: see my last comment for error...the signature is System.Collections.Generic.List<SyncLib.ClientWCF.Client>

Comment: and what is the method signature of Get_Clients? Seems strange they are thinking they are different classes.

Comment: @Sam1 Wait... are you referencing the same library as your service?

Comment: @iMortalitySX the get_clients method uses another serivce while synclient uses another service

Comment: @Sam1  You need to either change you services to use a common BaseClass and add knowntypes on the service contract(s) or convert from one to the other on your consumer.

Comment: @ChrisBint the signature of get_client is System.Collections.Generic.List<SyncLib.TaskEngine.Client>

Comment: See above. TaskEngine.Client != ClientWCF.Client

Comment: @ChrisBint I am getting another error saying : cannot convert type this to that...while they are the same class just being called from different service

Comment: @Sam1, no, they are being seen as different classes, you need to change that. Or explicitly convert them (dont just cast from one to the other)

Comment: how can i explicitly convert? I dont think I can change the class as it is used by other parts

Comment: You need to create an instance of class A and assign all properties from class B. Not pretty, but if you are unable to change the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is, when you create a service reference in WCF, *by default*, WCF will use an array for all (non-dictionary) collection types.  That will cause a method defined in a service like so:

```
public void SyncClient(List<Client> client)
{
```

To map through in the service reference as:

```
public void SyncClient(Client[] client)
```

This is a configurable option - in the "Create Service Reference" dialog, you can have WCF use a `List<T>` instead of an array, in which case your code will work.

Alternatively, you can just convert the object to an array (via `ToArray()`) when calling the service reference, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
WCF.SyncClient wcfSer = new WCF.SyncClient();
 Client[] clientModified = secondservice.Get_Clients(ModifiedDate, modifiedUnt).ToArray();
wcfSer.SyncClient(clientModified);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you add the service reference in visual studio to create the proxy. The Data Type section of the service reference settings has a drop down list for the Collection type. Check to see whether it is set to `System.Collections.Generic.List` or to `System.Array`.

In addition to this, if you have a reference to the assembly that defines the contract you can also check the `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` which will have the generated proxy to use the provided assembly instead of creating the new type.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion... don't use Visual Studio to gernerate proxy classes.  If you have all your objects and your Interface in a WCF library (without the actual service implemenation, because that should be separate anyways) why not just throw in the client and access it directly.  Here is all you have to do...

```
public class MyWCFClient:ClientBase<IMyWCFServiceContract>, IMyWCFServiceContract
{
    //Implement the interface and call the channel
    public void SyncClient(List<Client> clients)
    {
        this.Channel.SyncClient(clients);
    }
}
```

Then bam!  you have your proxy (client), and you are reutilizing all your DataContract classes that you created, to include any methods they do that you might want to take advantage of!  Check out [this CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33297/WCF-Proxy-Generation-Options) for a bit more on it.  This not only solved a very similar problem that I had, but also let me be much more flexible in my DataContract objects, so I could use them for more than just passing data.

This method can keep you out of trouble when messing with multiple services as well, as the VS service gererator likes to create some namespace that is related to your current namespace.  If you have the libraries go crazy.

If you do not have access to these libraries, don't totally disreguard, as you can gernate the code through a method described in the above [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33297/WCF-Proxy-Generation-Options) and custimize the code as well (including namespaces).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JSONdataLogin);
string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<WsShoeClass> OBJ = jss.Deserialize<List<WsShoeClass>>(JSONdata);
```

---

```
foreach (var Images in OBJ)
{  
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UploadShoeImage", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", Images.UserId));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShoeId", Images.ShoeId));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShoeImage", Images.ShoeImage));
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
}
```